# Angular material: dynamically change button color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button with 3 possible states:

1. Clickable
2. Disabled
3. Active

The button's code is like this:

```
<button mat-raised-button
              color="primary"
              [disabled]="anotherStarted"
              (click)="startButton = true">START</button>
```

The button is `primary` when clickable. It is disabled when another process has started.

What I can't figure out from the documentations is how to change its color to note it is now active (e.g. when startButton is true).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: please check this:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can do this in several ways.

**Option 1: Using Material colour variations**

According the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api) color is also an input, hence you can bind any property you want. Here any means material `ThemePalette`. Ex: Primary, Warn and Accent

```html
<button mat-raised-button
              [color]="paletteColour"
              [disabled]="anotherStarted"
              (click)="startButton = true; change()">START</button>
```

On your component,

```js
paletteColour = 'primary';
change() {
 paletteColour = 'warn';
}
```

This is just to give you an idea how to change the button colour using the material ThemePalette. Use your own logic to change colour.

You'll notice this is pretty basic and limited. So we'll look at option 2.

**Option 2: Using angular style property bindings**

Using Angular `style.background-color` property you can bind any colour you want.

```html
<button mat-raised-button
              [style.background-color]="btnColour"
              [disabled]="anotherStarted"
              (click)="startButton = true; change()">START</button>
```

On your component,

```js
btnColour= 'red';
change() {
 btnColour= 'green';
}
```

Hope you can get a clear idea about changing the `mat-button` colour dynamically. Use your own logic.!

Comment: Yes. I've just checked the source code and wanted to write the answer but you beat me to it. Thanks!

Comment: @yccteam was just trying to help yo. 

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is:

```
<button mat-raised-button
             [color]="(anotherStarted) ? 'warn' : 'primary'"
             [disabled]="anotherStarted"
             (click)="startButton = true">START</button>
```